# JDBC Mapping a join of the same table using an existing RowMapper

Tags: java, mysql, spring-jdbc

I have a query that joins a table with itself:

```
SELECT * FROM data d1 join data d2 ON d1.id != d2.id WHERE ...
```

And I already have a `RowMapper` for `Data`, which is the java object of the table `data`. Now, I could go and map the fields one by one and construct two Data objects:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper()
        {

            @Override
            public Object mapRow(ResultSet arg0, int arg1) throws SQLException
            {
                Data d1 = new Data();
                Date d2 = new Date();
                Data [] duple = new Data []{d1, d2};

                d1.setId(arg0.getLong(1));
                d1.setRegistryName(arg0.getString(2));
                ...
                d2.setId(arg0.getLong(11));
                d2.setRegistryName(arg0.getString(12));
                ...

                return duple;
            }
        });
```

But, that's a lot of manual work. So I can use my `DataRowMapper` to map the first object, but then I'll have to map the second one manually:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper()
        {

            @Override
            public Object mapRow(ResultSet arg0, int arg1) throws SQLException
            {
                Data d1 = new Data();
                Date d2 = new Date();
                Data [] duple = new Data []{d1, d2};
                d1 = new DataRowMapper<ShopSyncInfo>(Data.class).mapRow(arg0, arg1);

                d2.setId(arg0.getLong(11));
                d2.setRegistryName(arg0.getString(12));
                ...

                return duple;
            }
        });
```

So I would like to map the second object in the same way. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There is support for mapping a one-to-many relationship provided in the [Spring Data JDBC Extensions](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jdbc-ext/) project. See the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/core.support.html#core.support.onetomany). You would need to add this project to your build. However, you don't need the extra Oracle support so the following dependency is sufficient:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I would think that you could adapt this for a one-to-one mapping as well.